# Spring Boot - JAVA_OPTS in application.properties for .bash_profile?

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

Have a Spring Boot Microservice as the following version:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Have the microservice setup as a jar file (which has an embedded tomcat container)...

Need to set JAVA_OPTS like this this:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses";
```

Can I set this in application.properties or does it need to be inside .bash_profile?

Answer (score 1):

JAVA_OPTS is a common environment variable that can be optionally used by scripts within a shell. It is normally used to store preferred Java JVM system properties.

These properties need to be specified when the java command is executed.

`java -jar app.jar -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses`.

So, the question becomes, does the script that runs your spring boot application use this environment variable when executing your application? If the answer is no or you do not have a custom script then setting the environment variable will have no effect.

Comment: I have my Spring Boot Mircroservice running as a service as follows: sudo service app start | stop | restart | status. So, I don't explicitly run using java -jar. Should this be inside .bash_profile or inside application.properties?